# Can Bernays reflection scheme be formalized in mono-sorted FOL?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms, reflection

Working in *mono-sorted* first order logic with equality $``="$ and membership $``\in"$:

- *Define:* $set(x) \equiv_{df} \exists y \,  (x \in y)$
- Axiomatize:

1. **Extensionality:** $( a \subseteq b \land b \subseteq a \to a=b)$
2. **Separation:** $(set(a) \to \exists \ set \ x : \forall y \, (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \land \phi ))$
3. **Reflection:** $ \forall \ sets \ \vec{ a_i}, \, \forall \vec {b_i} \ (\varphi \to \exists \ set \ x : \text { trs}(x) \land \varphi^x)$

where formulas $\phi, \varphi$ do not use defined symboles, whose parameters are among $\vec{a_i}, \vec{b_i}$ symbols; $\varphi^x$ is obtained from $\varphi$ by merely bounding all of its quantifiers by $``\subseteq x"$ and replacing  each $b_i$ parameter by $b_i \cap x$. $``\text { trs}" $ stands for *is transitive*.

The idea is to see if this is known to succeed in capturing Bernays reflection schema. Here, the language is mono-sorted, and the idea is if the $\subseteq $ bound and the differential treatment of parameters is enough for that equivalance.

> Is the above Reflection equivalent to [Bernays reflection](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220366286_Bernays_and_Set_Theory) (page 21) over the rest of axioms of this theory?